# Cygwin - how do I search scrollback?

Tags: terminal, cygwin

Going to be pretty depressed if this is not a feature by now. To be clear, by scrollback, I mean scrolling up and down on the terminal emulator to see history.

Comment: What is your terminal emulator? Mintty? Do you mean scrolling in the command prompt to see previous commands (history) or scrolling the complete window to see the terminal buffer? Are you trying to seach previous commands (history) or the screen buffer? What shell are you using? bash?

Comment: Using cygwin? Entire terminal buffer. Bash

Comment: Scrolling with the mouse wheel works for me in mintty. What exactly is not working for you? Are you trying to scroll with the keyboard?

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + H, or Alt + F3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### How do I scroll up and down in mintty to see the terminal buffer?

To scroll in `mintty` use one of the following:

Mouse:

- scrolling behaviour is normal like any other windows window

Keyboard:

- <kbd>shift</kbd> followed by <kbd>up arrow</kbd> or <kbd>down arrow</kbd> will scroll the terminal buffer by a single line
- <kbd>shift</kbd> followed by <kbd>page up</kbd> or <kbd>page down</kbd> will scroll the terminal buffer by a page

To change the modifier key from <kbd>shift</kbd>:

1. Click the top left icon (which drops down the menu).
2. Select "Options".
3. Select "Window".
4. Change Modifier for Scrolling" as appropriate.

   You can also choose to allow <kbd>page up</kbd> or <kbd>page down</kbd> to work **without** a modifier.
5. Press "Apply", then "OK".

   [image]